# How to write dates in 2 lines using the Friggeri CV template?

Tags: xetex, cv, friggeri-cv

Under the 'Experience' section, I would like to add the following dates under a job position, separated in 2 lines:

Jan 2010 - Jul 2012

Jan 2014 - Jun 2015

However, writing

```
{{Jan 2010 - Jul 2012, 
Jan 2014 - Jun 2015}}
```

forces the dates to be written on one line and pushes the indent to the right. How can I add another? (See image below)

[image]

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}                   
\begin{document}
\header{somebody}{iusedtoknow}{fresh graduate}
%-------------------------
\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
{Jan 2010 - Jul 2012}
{Cupcakes 'n' Such}
{Cupcake Monster}
{\begin{itemize}
\item Take pictures of cupcakes all day long
\item Manage cupcake inventory and liase with other firms
\item Demonstrate how to eat cupcakes to customers without touching lips
\end{itemize}
}

\end{entrylist}
%-------------------------
\end{document}
```

**MWE - list environment in .cls file**:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.7pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  {\small #1}   &   \parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
            \textbf{#2}%
            \hfill%
            {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
            #4\vspace{\parsep}%
        }\\
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Hi @egreg. I just added an MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the .cls file for entrylist:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll |}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \parbox[t]{3.2cm}{#1}&\parbox[t]{10.6cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Above, I am wrapping the first column contents (#1) in a parbox so that you can fix and control the spacing.  We then shrink the second column so that it doesn't overrun the margin.  I also added some inter-column spacing in the entrylist definition.  Then in your .tex file, use a `\newline` as follows:

```
\entry
{Jan 2010 - Jul 2012\newline
Jan 2014 - Jun 2015}
{Cupcakes 'n' Such}
{Cupcake Monster}
{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{itemize}
\item Take pictures of cupcakes all day long
\item Manage cupcake inventory and liase with other firms
\item Demonstrate how to eat cupcakes to customers without touching lips
\end{itemize}
}
```

If you want the blue color then:

```
\entry
{Jan 2010 - Jul 2012\newline
{\addfontfeature{Color=blue}Jan 2014 - Jun 2015}}
{Cupcakes 'n' Such}
{Cupcake Monster}
{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{itemize}
\item Take pictures of cupcakes all day long
\item Manage cupcake inventory and liase with other firms
\item Demonstrate how to eat cupcakes to customers without touching lips
\end{itemize}
}
```

This produces the output as:

[image: Two line dates]

Because the default helvetica font doesn't have equal spacing for each letter, the dates won't line up exactly.  You'll need to switch fonts for that.  But I think this achieves your desired effect.  In order to achieve this though I've had to push the second column further to the right so you are sacrificing space.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}                   
\begin{document}
\header{somebody}{iusedtoknow}{fresh graduate}
%-------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
123 Street Name
City, Province A2B 3C4
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\href{mailto:john@doe.com}{john@doe.com}
\href{http://www.johndoe.com}{http://www.johndoe.com}
\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
english
spanish
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
{Jan 2010 - Jul 2012\newline
Jan 2014 - Jun 2015}
{Cupcakes 'n' Such}
{Cupcake Monster}
{\vspace{-10pt}\begin{itemize}
\item Take pictures of cupcakes all day long
\item Manage cupcake inventory and liase with other firms
\item Demonstrate how to eat cupcakes to customers without touching lips
\end{itemize}
}

\end{entrylist}
%-------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! But the MWE that you gave me still did not solve the problem. The 2 ranges of dates are forced in one line and pushes the indent to the right.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by pushing the indent to the right.  What is it that you want instead?  The two lines are separate on my document and not forced into one line when I test.  Can you edit your answer and provide the relevant lines for \entry and \entrylist from your .cls file as well as a small MWE for the CV itself so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I just added the MWE for the CV and the .cls file.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer again, have a look and see if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to adjust the parameters, because the result is far from ideal, but the idea can be of using a nested tabular:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{friggeri-cv}

\newcommand{\manylines}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\header{somebody}{iusedtoknow}{fresh graduate}
%-------------------------
\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry
  {\manylines{Jan 2010 -- Jul 2012\\Jan 2014 - Jun 2015}}
  {Cupcakes 'n' Such}
  {Cupcake Monster}
  {Here's what I did
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Take pictures of cupcakes all day long
   \item Manage cupcake inventory and liase with other firms
   \item Demonstrate how to eat cupcakes to customers without touching lips
   \end{itemize}
  }

\end{entrylist}
%-------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]